# Update LWR site Head Markup with metatdata

Tags: salesforcedx, experience-cloud, lwr

Is there any option to deploy head markup of a LWR site with SFDX and metadata instead of modifying it manually in the Advanced section of the Experience Builder site settings (following these steps [described in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/template_differences_markup.htm)) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SFDX and deploy the whole Experience Bundle, info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm)